# Clear server validation message before submit

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, message

To replicate the issue:

1. Create an ASP.NET MVC 3 page with server validation.
2. Submit with validation error.
3. Server validation error appears in red.
4. Correct the validation error and submit again, then Success
   redirected to another report page.
5. On clicking the Back button on the report page, the validation error
   message still showing on the original form.

Users getting annoyed seeing the server validation message when clicking the back button.

- I would not consider a solution to disable the back button.
- I would not consider a solution to refresh the page on clicking the
  back button.

**I would consider the server validation message to disappear before making the successful form submission or any other valid solution.**

Thanks

Comment: But still do you want BACK BUTTON with the SUBMIT behavior? strange

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods for clearing history so that back button will not show remembered page: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout

Answer (score 0):

To avoid seeing the validation message, I disable the cache so browser will automatically reload the page when users click Back button.  However, users would see a form resubmission warning if the page was previously submitted using `POST` method.  To workaround this, I use javascript `window.history.back()` to change a `POST` request back to the prior `GET` request if the ModelState is not valid.

Here are the details...

Create two functions in controller: one with `[HttpGet]` attribute and one with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

In the `HttpPost` version, add following logics...

1. If ModelState is invalid, save ModelState and form/model data to TempData
2. Return a simple View that contains javascript like following.

   <html>
   <body>
   <script>window.history.back();
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>

In the `HttpGet` version,

1. Add attribute `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`
2. Add logic to load ModelState and model data from TempData
3. Pass model data to View